# can't get the product id in single woocommerce page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In the single woocommerce page where I have actions like `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` to show the products, I can't access the product id. I tried the following codes and it didn't work :

```
$post->ID
get_the_ID()
$product->id
$product->get_id()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `$product` and `$post`, then you need to use `global $product;` and `global $post` to get access to them. Did you do that?

```
global $product;

$product_id = $product->get_id();
```

Comment: I did it, and I got this error: `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on null`

Comment: Where are you putting the code? How are you hooking into `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary`?